# Macro for nested IF statement

Tags: if-statement, macros, embed

Good day,

I am trying to insert a multiple IF statement into a macro, but getting an error on the "50" saying "Expected end IF statement". I never did nested if statements through a macro, can someone advise on the best approach for this? thanks
Maybe I should have if else else etc... similar to other coding languages (c++, java, etc)?

```
Sub Step9_IF_1()
Dim strFirstFile As String
Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim wbkLookup As Workbook
Dim clLookup As Range
Dim clDest As Range
Dim rws As Long

strFirstFile = "Z:\AR\AR PROGRESS\2014\MENACA REPORTS\0MENACA Working File\AR Working File\UAE\Working File - UAE.xlsx"
Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)


With wbk1.Sheets("sheet1")
    Set clDest = .Range("YC1")
End With

If clLookup.Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then
    rws = Range(clLookup, clLookup.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Set clDest = clDest.Resize(rws, 1)
End If

clDest.Formula =  "=IF(ClDest<>70,C2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*PD*",B2)),"50",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*OD*",B2)),"50",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*OC*",B2)),"50",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*OF*",B2)),"50",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*PC*",B2)),"50",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*MS*",B2)),"50","70")))))))"

clDest.Value = clDest.Value ' Convert to value
wbk1.Close True

MsgBox ("IF Step 1 - Completed!!")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I managed to answer the question
Marking answer down for future reference, for my buddies in need of guidance :)

```
Sub Step9_IF_1()
Dim strFirstFile As String
Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim wbkLookup As Workbook
Dim clLookup As Range
Dim clDest As Range
Dim rws As Long

strFirstFile = "C:\Users\hayekn\Desktop\IF Statement.xlsx"
Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)


With wbk1.Sheets("sheet1")
    Set clDest = .Range("L2")
    Set clLookup = .Range("C2")
End With

If clLookup.Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then
    rws = Range(clLookup, clLookup.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Set clDest = clDest.Resize(rws, 1)
End If

clDest.Formula = "=IF(" & clLookup.Address(False, False) & " <>70," & clLookup.Address(False, False) & ",IF(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""*PD*"",""*OD*"",""*OC*"",""*OF*"",""*PC*"",""*MS*""}," & clLookup.Address(False, False) & ")),""50"",""70""))"

clDest.Value = clDest.Value ' Convert to value

wbk1.Close True
MsgBox ("IF Step 1 - Completed!!")

End Sub
```